# Some identities with the Riemann-Hurwitz zeta function

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, quantum-field-theory, renormalization

The only definition that I have ever seen of this Riemann-Hurtwitz zeta-function is this,

For $0 < a \leq 1$ we have the identity
$$ \zeta(z, a) = \frac{2 \Gamma(1 - z)}{(2 \pi)^{1-z}} \left[\sin \frac{z \pi}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos 2 \pi a n}{n^{1-z}}
   + \cos \frac{z \pi}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin 2 \pi a n}{n^{1-z}} \right] \,$$

- Now from this (or otherwise!) how do I show that, $\xi(s,\frac{1}{2}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ (n + \frac{1}{2} )^s }$
- It seems that for any $k$ even and $d$ a positive integer there is such a sum over inverse powers representation of $\xi(s-k,\frac{d}{2}-1 )$  - it would be great to know if there is a general expression here!
- Any insight/motivation about this $\xi(z,a)$ function would be a great help.

Comment: Is $\zeta$ same as $\xi$?

Comment: A functional equation might help.

Comment: @user17762 Yes! Sorry for the typo!

Comment: @MustafaSaid May be you can elaborate...

Comment: @user6818, the Hurwitz zeta function satisfies the functional equation, $\zeta(1-s, \frac{m}{n}) = \frac{2 \Gamma (s)}{(2 \pi n)^s} \sum_{k=1}^n [\cos(\frac{\pi s}{2} - \frac{2\pi km}{n}) \zeta(s, k/n)]$ that holds for all values of $s$ and integers, $1 \leq m \leq n$.  Now let $m/n = 1/2$ and compare both sides of the functional equation.  I suspect that this will give you the desired expression for $\zeta(s, 1/2)$.

Comment: and the functional equation for $\zeta(s,a) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+a)^{-s}$ is proven as for $\zeta(s)$ from $\zeta(s,a) = s\int_0^\infty \lfloor x+1-a\rfloor x^{-s-1} dx = \frac{s}{s-1}+ 1-a + \int_0^\infty \{x+1-a\} x^{-s-1} dx $ and decomposing $\{x+1-a\}$ in Fourier series, then inverting $ \int$ and $\sum$, and using that $\int_0^\infty \sin(2 \pi nx) x^{-s-1} dx = n^{s-1}\int_0^\infty \sin(2 \pi x) x^{-s-1} dx$

Answer (score 3):

The definition of the Hurwitz-Riemann $\zeta$ function is:

\begin{eqnarray}
  \zeta(s, x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+x)^s} \quad , \quad  x>0 
\end{eqnarray}
with $s \in \mathbb{C} \; , \; \mathrm{Re}(s)>1$.

If $x=1$, Hurwitz-Riemann Zeta-function is reduced  the original 
Riemann Zeta function.  That is, by default we assume $\zeta(s,1)=\zeta(s)$.

Now, there are hundreds of representations of the Hurwitz-Riemann Zeta-function. The one you show is just one of them.